Unacceptable results for adj R2
I have a dataset with 19 features. When I ran it with the Lasso algorithm. R2 for test and train was 0.69. But the value of adj r2 for test is 1.28 (above 1), and for train the value is 0.28. What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it? I used the following formula.
def adj_r2_score(y_true, y_pred, n_samples, n_features):
r2 = r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
adj_r2 = 1 - ((1 - r2) * (n_samples - 1) / (n_samples - n_features - 1))
return adj_r2

n_samples_train = len(y_train)
n_samples_test = len(y_test)
n_features = X_train.shape[1]

adj_r2_train = adj_r2_score(y_train, train_pred, n_samples_train, n_features)
adj_r2_test = adj_r2_score(y_test, test_pred, n_samples_test, n_features)

print(f'adj r2 train {adj_r2_train}')
print(f'adj r2 test {adj_r2_test}')

n_samples_train = 35
n_samples_test = 10
n_features = 20

The result that R^2 is between zero relates to in-sample results and one uses algebraic properties of OLS estimation - at least those that I know - with a constant (or something that can be linearly combined into a constant) and hence need not carry over to OOS R^2, or its adjusted version, for models fitted with other algorithms such as LASSO

Thank you but for other models like linear, knn , dct also have this problem:(

Adjustment is needed when not splitting the data or when focusing only on the training sample.  For test samples no further penalty for estimating all those parameters is called for since the model developed from the training sample was “frozen”.  So adjusted $R^2$ is not used in independent test samples.

@ErfanMollai, a MWE would then seem useful here

Thank you so much @FrankHarrell

@ChristophHanck I'm sorry, is there a place where I can see an example of this method?

@ChristophHanck, what is MWE?

Sorry, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example: A minimal reproducible example may also be referred to as a reprex, a minimal working example (MWE), a minimal complete verifiable example (MCVE), or a short self-contained correct example (SSCCE).

@ChristophHanck thanks

I argue here that an adjusted $R^2$ presents some problems when it comes to machine learning models like KNN, as it becomes difficult or (nearly) impossible to get a handle on the degrees of freedom to get the unbiased estimator of variance used in the usual calculation of adjusted $R^2$ in OLS linear regression.
